# Pivot_wider with sum in R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I am hoping to generate turn each unique `path` column into column headers and have a count showing the number of times it shows up within a `visitlink` group. This is a snippet of my dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(visitlink = c("715296","715296","715296","715296","715296","1214080","1214080","1214080","1214080","1214080"),
                 path = c("3_0_1_0","3_0_1_0","0_0_1_0","0_0_0_3","0_0_0_1","1_0_1_0","0_1_0_0","0_0_1_0","0_0_1_0","0_0_0_1"))
```

Below is my current code, but unfortunately it is only 1 or 0 and does not sum the total number of unique `path` within a `visitlink` group

```
df2<- pivot_wider(df, names_from = path , values_from = path , values_fn = ~1, values_fill = 0)
```

This is my output, but path `3_0_1_0` should be 2 for visitlink `715296` for example.
[image]

Comment: use `values_fn = length` instead

Comment: Can't you just use `table` here? For example `table(df$visitlink, df$path)`?

Comment: both work! maybe submit as an answer @AllanCameron

Comment: as suggested by @AllanCameron `table(df)` should work